# File (.txt) cannot be found

Tags: java, android-studio

I am creating a stock market simulator (beginner) and I made a .txt file to save the stock symbol and name within a file. I am having an issue where my code is unable to find the file on my desktop.

```
public static void load() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("/Users/dhruvchaudhari/Desktop/stocks.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while ((scan.hasNextLine())) {
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
    }
}
```

The error it is throwing is as such

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/*username*/Desktop/stocks.txt (No such file or directory)
```

I'm on Mac and I checked the directory for the file directory and it should be correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your Android app cannot directly access files on your development machine. Put the necessary data in your project's assets, and load it from there.

Comment: The error message doesn't agree with your code. What's the real code?

Comment: Your application may run in a virtual machine simulating a smartphone, not directly on Mac OS X

Comment: It seems that you run a pure Java program using AndroidStudio. If so, you'd better use Eclipse or normal IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @MikeM. I moved it into the asset folder, what would I change the pathName to inside the file line?

Comment: You don't use a `File`. You would need to use `Context#getAssets().open("stocks.txt")` to get an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current working directory to confirm the path of your file by adding `System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

this will return the path you can debug this to get the idea of path in your application.

Also you can add read the file if its not there the code will create it for so you can add your metadata into the generated file.
By using this approach I hope you can move ahead.

```
public static void load() throws IOException {
    File yourFile = new File(path);
    yourFile.createNewFile(); // if file already exists will do nothing
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(yourFile);
    while ((scan.hasNextLine())) {
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously your path is wrong or the file doesn't exist. You can use the if statement to determine whether the file exists first, and create the file when it does not exist.